# How to not highlight values in comments in Emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs, comments, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight true and false values in some configuration files.  I've
done it this way:

```
(defun my/highlight-in-properties-files ()
  "Highlight regexps in PROPERTIES files."
  (when (string-match-p ".properties" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
    (highlight-regexp "true" 'hi-green)
    (highlight-regexp "false" 'hi-pink)))
```

But it also highlight those values in comments:

[image]

Is there a way to exclude those highlightings?

**UPDATE** -- `highlight-regexp` is an alias for ‘hi-lock-face-buffer’ in ‘hi-lock.el’.  And `string-match-p` is a compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.

Comment: Could you please add the value of `highlight-regexp` to the question?

Comment: And also, add `string-match-p`

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the regexps via `font-lock-add-keywords`, which will already account for the comment syntax in the buffer, eg.

```
(defun my-font-lock-additions ()
  (require 'hi-lock)                    ; fonts
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("\\btrue\\b"  . 'hi-green)
     ("\\bfalse\\b" . 'hi-pink)))
  (font-lock-flush))
```

And call `(font-lock-refresh-defaults)` to revert back to OG settings.

Sticking to a purely regexp solution with `highlight-regexp` will undoubtebly produce some mistakes in odd cases, but, I think just customizing your regex to check for a comment prefix would probably work well enough as well,

```
(defun my/highlight-in-properties-files ()
  "Highlight regexps in PROPERTIES files."
  (when (string-match-p ".properties" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
    (comment-normalize-vars)            ; ensure comment variables are setup
    (let ((cmt-re (format "^[^%s]*" (regexp-quote (string-trim comment-start)))))
      (highlight-regexp (format "%s\\(\\_<true\\_>\\)" cmt-re) 'hi-green 1)
      (highlight-regexp (format "%s\\(\\_<false\\_>\\)" cmt-re) 'hi-pink 1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to simply add a `$` at the end of your regex to not match the comments, as the true/false are always at the end, while those in comments are always situated in the middle of a sentence

```
(defun my/highlight-in-properties-files ()
  "Highlight regexps in PROPERTIES files."
  (when (string-match-p ".properties" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
    (highlight-regexp "true$" 'hi-green)
    (highlight-regexp "false$" 'hi-pink)))
```